# Android Retrofit 2 Simple XML Converter Response

Tags: java, android, xml, soap, retrofit

Estou usando Retrofit 2.2.0 e Retrofit SimpleXML Converter 2.2.0. Eu adicionei o simplexmlconverter na instancia do retrofit com o método addConverterFactory.

O problema é que quando eu recebo a resposta do servidor, acontece o seguinte erro

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Body' does not have a match in class ResponseEnvelope at line 1
```

Eu estou recebendo uma resposta do servidor em XML do seguinte modo:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:autenticarUsuarioPorEmailResponse xmlns:ns="http://business.curitiba.org.br">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2471:AutenticaUsuarioPorEmailSaida" xmlns:ax2471="http://saidas.curitiba.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2469="http://entities.curitiba.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax2467="http://entradas.curitiba.org/xsd">
            <ax2471:idCredencial>3282</ax2471:idCredencial>
            <ax2471:tokenAcesso>635E3DA9-7C02-4DB7-9653-E7688C66B02C</ax2471:tokenAcesso>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:autenticarUsuarioPorEmailResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**ResponseEnvelope.java**

```
@Root(name = "soapenv:Envelope")
@Namespace(prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class ResponseEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soapenv:Body", required = false)
    private ResponseBody body;

    public ResponseBody getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(ResponseBody body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

**ResponseBody.java**

```
@Root(name = "soapenv:Body", strict = false)
public class ResponseBody {

    @Element(name = "ns:cadastrarCredencialEmailResponse", required = false)
    private ResponseData requestData;

    public ResponseData getRequestData() {
        return requestData;
    }

    public void setRequestData(ResponseData requestData) {
        this.requestData = requestData;
    }

}
```

**ResponseData.java**

```
@Root(name = "ns:cadastrarCredencialEmailResponse", strict = false)
@Namespace(prefix = "ns", reference = "http://business.curitiba.org")
public class ResponseData {

    @Element(name = "ns:return", required = false)
    private ResponseInfo info;

    public ResponseInfo getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(ResponseInfo info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

**ResponseInfo.java**

```
@Root(name = "ns:return", strict = false)
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(prefix = "ax2471", reference = "http://saidas.curitiba.org/xsd"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "ax2469", reference = "http://entities.curitiba.org/xsd"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "xsi", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "ax2467", reference = "http://entradas.curitiba.org/xsd")
})
public class ResponseInfo {

    @Element(name = "ax2471:codigoAtivacao", required = false)
    private String codigoAtivacao;
    @Element(name = "ax2471:idCredencial", required = false)
    private String idCredencial;

    public String getCodigoAtivacao() {
        return codigoAtivacao;
    }

    public void setCodigoAtivacao(String codigoAtivacao) {
        this.codigoAtivacao = codigoAtivacao;
    }

    public String getIdCredencial() {
        return idCredencial;
    }

    public void setIdCredencial(String idCredencial) {
        this.idCredencial = idCredencial;
    }
}
```

Acho que o problema está na classe ResponseInfo, porque eu não sei como adicionar o atributo **xsi:type** e acho que isto que está causando o problema.

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.